# HttpPost gives Illegalstateexception

Tags: php, android

I am trying to connect to a localhost (WAMP) webservice I created using an httpPost request. It keeps failing and giving an IllegalStateExecption. Can anyone provide some insight to the problem? Thank you!

```
String songtext,artisttext;
HttpResponse response ;
EditText song;
EditText artist;
EditText party;
HttpPost post;
HttpClient client;
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
String URL = "http://10.0.2.2/GoDJ/index.php?r=request/create";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    song = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
    artist = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.songArtist);
    party = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.partyid);



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void uploadToDB(View view)
{
    //send user message
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Letting the DJ Know!!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
    //add values
    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("party", party.getText().toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", song.getText().toString()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("artist", artist.getText().toString()));

    try
    {
        //instantiate request
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        post = new HttpPost(URL);
        text = "Set Up Client and Post";
        toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        text = "Entity Set";
        toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
        response = client.execute(post);
        text = "Post Executed SUCCESS";
        toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        text = "FAILURE";
        toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are running on Android 4 and on the UI thread not allowed the networking

Pls use an Async task and it will sole the problem.

[Here](http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/) is an example how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use [this lib](http://androidannotations.org/)
and do the post call with method using `@Background` annotation.